# How to extract data from an HTML string in PHP

Tags: php, html, web, domxpath

I have got the follwing HTML string in which i need to access the value of a specific `id` .

The string is as follows

```js
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="userview.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
 <div>
 <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="test_value" />
 </div>
```

Now in order to access it i have written the following code

```js
$doc = new DOMDocument();
 @$doc->loadHTML($str);
 $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
 $spanner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@id, '__VIEWSTATE')]");
 foreach ($spanner as $node) 
     {
       echo $node->nodeValue;
     }
```

where `str` is my string. Now every time i run it , it returns a blank value

Comment: my question is is this form posted or not? ecouse if it is posted you can jsut acces it but its just a question i cant find the anwser on in your question

Comment: it is just a string .. i am actually scrapping a webpage in which there is this form , i just need to access the value of `__VIEWSTATE`

Answer (score 1):

Try this  in this `query` part has modified

```
$html = '<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="userview.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="adsadsadsdsadsd" />
</div>';
 $doc = new DOMDocument;
 $doc->loadHTML($html);
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
 $val= $xpath->query('//input[@type="hidden" and @id = "__VIEWSTATE"]/@value' 
 );
print_r($val[0]->nodeValue);
```